2020: a year in moderation

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months.
As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.
So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Quantitative Finance over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community¹




Users suspended²
5
10


Users destroyed³
32
0


Users contacted
7
0


Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue
72
486


Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue
20
129


Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue
26
152


Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue
29
203


Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue
58
1,712


Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue
108
1,534


Tag synonyms proposed
0
2


Tag synonyms created
1
0


Questions unprotected
0
2


Questions reopened
6
0


Questions protected
1
2


Questions migrated
10
0


Questions flagged⁵
0
84


Questions closed
365
286


Question flags handled⁵
71
13


Posts unlocked
0
1


Posts undeleted
17
43


Posts locked
0
15


Posts deleted⁶
203
1,237


Posts bumped
0
971


Comments undeleted
23
0


Comments flagged
0
42


Comments deleted⁷
83
1,552


Comment flags handled
36
6


Answers flagged
2
313


Answer flags handled
285
30


All comments on a post moved to chat
1
0



Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Quantitative Finance without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2019: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


A big thank you to Shog9 for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to Brian for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.
Wishing everyone a happy 2021!
